# Add column to SharePoint Online 2013 list via Powershell v3

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0, sharepoint-object-model

Can anybody tell me how to do this? None of the examples I have found seem to work.

My site is https://blah.sharepoint.com/technology and my list is called 'pfa'. I want to add some text columns.

I DO have connectivity with SharePoint Online via my Powershell, as I have managed to get some results back from various commands.

Thanks.

Comment: I, too, want to interact with PowerShell and SharePoint (no add-in, just REST via Invoke-RestMethod) but fall down with authenticating. Have you had any luck?

Comment: This link may help you. Good demo about how to add geo-location column in sharepoint using powersh [Learn Play and Code article](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/enable-geo-location-column-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

### How to provision field in SharePoint Online via CSOM in PowerShell

CSOM API comes with:

- [FieldCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.add(v=office.15).aspx) - adds a field to the field
  collection
- [FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml(v=office.15).aspx) - creates a field based on
  the specified schema, Boolean value, and field options

to add a list or site column.

The example below demonstrates how to add `GeoLocation` field into `Contacts` List:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

function Provision-Field([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[string]$ListTitle,[string]$FieldSchema)
{
   $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
   $List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($FieldSchema,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
   $Context.Load($List)
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}



$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$URL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($URL)
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Credentials

Provision-Field $Context "Contacts" "<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Location'/>"
```

### How to provision field in SharePoint Online via REST in PowerShell

Endpoints:

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/fields('<field id>')

http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'<list id>')/fields('<field id>')
```

The article [Consuming the SharePoint 2013 REST API from PowerShell](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/) describes how send  HTTPS requests to SharePoint REST web services.

Using the [Invoke-RestSPO](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/10713514#file-invoke-restspo-ps1) function from the article, the following example demonstrates how to add Note field to List using REST API in PowerShell:

```
Function Add-SPOField(){

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$WebUrl,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$UserName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$Password,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$ListTitle,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$FieldTitle,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[System.Int32]$FieldType
)


    $fieldMetadata = @{ 
      __metadata =  @{'type' = 'SP.Field' }; 
      Title = $FieldTitle;
      FieldTypeKind = $FieldType;
    } | ConvertTo-Json


   $Url = $WebUrl + "_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + $ListTitle +  "')/fields"

   $contextInfo = Get-SPOContextInfo $WebUrl $UserName $Password
   Invoke-RestSPO $Url Post $UserName $Password $fieldMetadata $contextInfo.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
}




. ".\Invoke-RestSPO.ps1"   #InInvoke-RestSPO function

$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" 
$WebUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"


Add-SPOField -WebUrl $WebUrl -UserName $UserName -Password $Password -ListTitle "Documents" -FieldTitle "Comments" -FieldType 3
```

### References

- [Fields REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Consuming the SharePoint 2013 REST API from PowerShell](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is someone who created a list with the CSOM through PowerShell with SharePoint Oneline http://www.hartsteve.com/2013/06/sharepoint-online-powershell/

The PowerShell stuff for SharePoint online is limited to some basic admin tasks only. When you used the CSOM in PowerShell, you can do a lot more.